# What is the simplest program I can write to invoke a batch script?

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

It is very stupid that windows will not let you add batch files to your quick launch or whatever they call in in windows 7. That bar across the bar, i can attach firefox there, command prompt, even paint (my favorite), but not a batch file. I can "pin" it to another program, which is just weird. I want it to standalone, the batch file does enough work by itself.

So lets say i have batch file. What is the simplest executable program I can write to invoke said script. Then I can finally pin all my useful batch files on that quick-jump-pin-bar.

Answer (score 5):

If I remember right, you can do this by first pinning a shortcut to CMD.exe to the taskbar. Then edit the command, and change `CMD.exe` to `CMD.exe /c MyBatchFile.bat`.  I believe this will execute the batch file.

Comment: this does not work. i can only have one command prompt pinned on my bar at a time. i have (now) 4 batch scripts and maybe more to come, i want them all on the bottom. this is why i need a simple executable program to pin.

Comment: Well that sucks...I've got another answer here, hopefully that one will work for you if you can't find anything better.

Comment: I created a shortcut to a batch file first, edited it to run `cmd /c C:\Users\Me\foo.cmd` and it *did* work. Also no problems in pinning it to the taskbar, even though I have `cmd` already pinned.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only pin one cmd, here's an alternative, assuming you have the .NET framework installed - a very simple C# application:

Populate a textfile with the following contents:

```
class Program {
  static void Main() {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\test.bat");
  }
}
```

where `Program` is the name of the executable you want to create, and `c:\test.bat` is the full path to the batch file. Save the file as `Program.cs`.  Execute the following from the command line:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe Program.cs
```

You can replace `2.0.50727` with whatever directory exists on your machine - might be 1.1.something or 3.5 or 4.0.something - it's all the same for this scenario.

This will generate Program.exe. You can put that exe file wherever you want, and pin that executable to the taskbar. You can discard the .cs file once you're done making your executables.

Kind of a crappy solution, but it should work, assuming you don't find anything better. And if you don't have the .NET framework (which I'm not sure is even possible in Windows 7), you can install it pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a folder, put your batch files in it, and pin the folder to the menu bar :D

You can also write a startup script, so the batch file will be executed on startup, but I don't know if you want to run those scripts on every bootup... You can also add the command prompt to the bar, and edit the startup path..

Answer (score 0):

Use command switches on [CMD.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true).

```
cmd.exe /c "myscript.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a sort of workaround you could use the following trick. Pin an arbitrary application to the task bar, Shift+right click on the pinned icon, select Properties, change 'Target' and 'Start in' accordingly. Rename it too if you like.

You can pin more than one .bat file using this technique.